# Swhat are possible values of $k$ in this construction of a sequence?

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

> If there is an integer $k$ such that the sum of the first $k-1$ positive integers is equal to $(k+1)+(k+2)+\cdots +n$, with $n$ representing the last integer in the sequence, which of the following is/are possible values of $k$?
> Choose all that apply.

1. $35$
2. $46$
3. $85$
4. $160$
5. $204$

The answer is somehow calculated using$$\frac{n(n+1)}{2}=\frac{k(k-1)}{2}+\frac{(k+1)k}{2},$$ which is informally means that the sum below $k^th$ term is equal to the sum above $k.$

But How does one know to exclude the possivity that

- $$\frac{n(n+1)}{2}=\frac{k(k-1)}{2}+\frac{(k)k}{2},$$
- $$\frac{n(n+1)}{2}=\frac{k(k-1)}{2}+\frac{(k-1)k}{2},$$
- $$\frac{n(n+1)}{2}=\frac{k(k-1)}{2}+\frac{(k+2)k}{2},$$

The sequence $\{X_p\}$has length $r$. $X_1=1$, $X_r=n$.

The number of terms excluding the first $k-1$ equals $r-(k-1)=r-k+1$. Do I have to know $r$?

Based on the $k+1,k+2,\ldots ,k+c$ relation, I think the first $k-1$ integers are consecutive but I am not sure as this is a sum formula, and not a sequence. I do not know whether the sequence is consecutive for $p>k-1$.

The sum of the sequence: $$1+2+3+...+n= 1+2+3+...+(k-1)+k+k+1+...+n$$

Comment: You may safely assume that $...$ is consecutive integers, unless stated otherwise. Even though formally this is a bit finicky.

Comment: "The sum of the first $k-1$ positive integers" is just the sum $1 + 2 + \cdots + (k-1)$. These terms are always consecutive.

Comment: Do you know how to sum an arithmetic series?  Your first equation is incorrect.  The last term should be $\frac {(k+n)(n-k+1)}2$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not that hard! We need $1+2+...+(k-1)=(k+1)+....+n$. Which gives on the r.h.s $1+2+.....+n-(1+2+3+....+k)$

$\dfrac{k(k-1)}{2}=\dfrac{n(n+1)}{2}-\dfrac{k(k+1)}{2}$ giving:

$k^{2}=\dfrac{n(n+1)}{2}$. $1)$ Setting $k=35$ we get $n=49$ which is acceptable because it is a natural number!

$2),3),4)$ are rejected because they give fractional or irrational

numbers for $n$ and $5)$ for $n=288$ we get $(204)^{2}=144.289$ so the

value $204$ is acceptable.

Thus only $1)$ and $5)$ are acceptable answers!

Comment: How do you show that $1+2+...+(k-1)=(k+1)+....+n \iff \dfrac{k(k-1)}{2}=\dfrac{n(n+1)}{2}-\dfrac{k(k+1)}{2}.$@GeorgeTsoutsinos

Comment: Because$ 1+2+...+(k-1)=k(k-1)/2$ and we add and subtract $1+2+3+...+k$ on the r.h.s. Don't worry it is correct!

Comment: I am not convinced.

Comment: Read the edit I just wrote!

Comment: There is no mystery! We just write $(k+1)+....+n=1+2+.....+n-(1+2+...+k)$. Are you still not convinced?

Comment: How do you know the equality is not $1+2+...+(k-1)=(k+1)+....+n$. Which gives on the r.h.s $$1+2+.....+n-(1+2+3+....+*k+1*)$$ or Which gives on the r.h.s $$1+2+.....+n-(1+2+3+....+*k-1*)$$? @GeorgeTsoutsinos.

Comment: Because as I told you the r.h.s is $(k+1)+(k+2)+....+n \,\,$which is $(k+1)+(k+2)+...+n+(1+2+....+k)-(1+2+.....+k)=(1+2+.....+n)-(1+2+....+k)$.

Comment: I can't make it simpler than this!